# Parse string containing range of values to min and max variables

Tags: php

I'm looking for a nice way to parse a string into two variables using PHP. The variables are called minage and maxage, and they should be parsed according to the examples below:

```
"40" -> minage=40, maxage=40
"-40" -> minage=null, maxage=40
"40-" -> minage=40, maxage=null
"40-60" -> minage=40, maxage=60
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$minrange = null;
$maxrange = null;
$parts = explode('-', $str);
switch (count($parts)) {
case 1:
    $minrange = $maxrange = intval($parts[0]);
    break;
case 2:
    $minrange = $parts[0] == "" ? null : intval($parts[0]);
    $maxrange = $parts[1] == "" ? null : intval($parts[1]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This unexplained answer DOES properly handle zero values in range expressions. https://3v4l.org/7T7ct

Answer (score 2):

You could also encapsulate the data in a class, say Range:

```
class Range {

  protected $min;
  protected $max;

  public function __construct($str) {
    if(preg_match('/^\d+$/', $str)) {
      $this->min = (int)$str;
      $this->max = (int)$str;
    } else {
      preg_match('/^(\d*)-(\d*)$/', $str, $matches);
      $this->min = $matches[1] ? (int)$matches[1] : null;
      $this->max = $matches[2] ? (int)$matches[2] : null;
    }
  }

  // more functions here like contains($value) and/or min() and max()

  public function __toString() {
    return 'min=' . $this->min . ', max=' . $this->max;
  }
}

$tests = array('40', '-40', '40-', '40-60');
foreach($tests as $t) {
  echo new Range($t) . "\n";
}
```

which produces:

```
min=40, max=40
min=, max=40
min=40, max=
min=40, max=60
```

Of course, you could replace the `preg_` calls with some "normal" string functions, but the only thing I know of PHP is some regex-trickery.

Comment: This is a good idea, but why make the variables protected? Presumably you want to be able to access the data you've extracted, otherwise there's no point...

Comment: @Matthew, yes, they could be made public, or leave them protected and provide extra methods in the Range class (which I left out).

Comment: Due to loose comparisons, this answer isn't well suited to parsing zero values. https://3v4l.org/JJh7M

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode("-", $str);
$minage = NULL;
$maxage = NULL;
if (count($parts) == 1) {
  $minage = intval($parts[0]);
  $maxage = $minage;
}
else if ((count($parts) >= 2) && is_numeric($parts[0]) && is_numeric($parts[1])) {
  $minage = intval($parts[0]);
  $maxage = intval($parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: This unexplained answer fails on 2 of 4 test strings. https://3v4l.org/ITKIX

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will correctly handle 0 values in the range expression with only one `preg_` function call.

I'll add a helper function which will cast non-null values to an integer data type.  Of course, if this casting is not critical, it can be omitted and the extracted values will be `null` or string type.

Essentially, the regex makes all components in the string optional and gives priority to the max age when populating the array of matches.  The hyphen is captured to determine whether the max age should be used to replace the `null` min age.

The null coalescing assignment operator (`??=`) means that the following condition is only executed if `$minAge` is `null`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CBAg0))

```
$ranges = [
    "40",    // minage=40, maxage=40
    "-40",   // minage=null, maxage=40
    "40-",   // minage=40, maxage=null
    "40-60", // minage=40, maxage=60
    "0",     // minage=0, maxage=0
    "-0",    // minage=null, maxage=0
    "0-",    // minage=0, maxage=null
    "0-0"
];

function nullableInt(?int $v) { return $v; }

foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    [, $minAge, $hyphen, $maxAge] = preg_match('/^(\d+)??(-)?(\d+)?$/', $range, $m, PREG_UNMATCHED_AS_NULL) ? $m : [null, null, null, null];
    $minAge ??= ($hyphen ? null : $maxAge);
    var_export(['minAge' => nullableInt($minAge), 'maxAge' => nullableInt($maxAge)]);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  'minAge' => 40,
  'maxAge' => 40,
)
array (
  'minAge' => NULL,
  'maxAge' => 40,
)
array (
  'minAge' => 40,
  'maxAge' => NULL,
)
array (
  'minAge' => 40,
  'maxAge' => 60,
)
array (
  'minAge' => 0,
  'maxAge' => 0,
)
array (
  'minAge' => NULL,
  'maxAge' => 0,
)
array (
  'minAge' => 0,
  'maxAge' => NULL,
)
array (
  'minAge' => 0,
  'maxAge' => 0,
)
```